# C++ environment variable expansion

Tags: c++, strings, c++11

I wrote the following a while ago (using regex code I found on Stack Overflow), and I have the following concern I'd like addressed: should there be an `std::move()` around the passing of the string into the parameter in the second version of the function, `ExpandEnv(std::string const &text)`, to the rvalue version? Conversely, is there any reason not to use it?

```
inline std::string GetEnv(char const var[])
{
#if defined _WIN32 // getenv() is deprecated on Windows
    char *buf{nullptr};
    size_t sz;
    std::string val;
    if (_dupenv_s(&buf, &sz, var) || buf == nullptr) return val;
    val = buf;
    free(buf);
    return val;
#else
    return getenv(var);
#endif
}

inline std::string ExpandEnv(std::string &&text)
{
    static const std::regex ENV{"\\$\\{([^}]+)\\}"};
    std::smatch match;
    while (std::regex_search(text, match, ENV)) text.replace(match.begin()->first, match[0].second, GetEnv(match[1].str().c_str()));
    return text;
}

inline std::string ExpandEnv(std::string const &text)
{
    return ExpandEnv(std::string(text));
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to overload `ExpandEnv`.  In the const-ref overload, your action is to make a copy of the argument and pass that to the rvalue-ref version.

There's a simple way to get the compiler to do that, and it's **pass by value**.  Often overlooked, this is exactly the right way to get a modifiable value in your function, by move if possible, and by value if not:

```
inline std::string ExpandEnv(std::string text)
{
    //...implementation
}
```

To answer your specific question (even though we've eliminated the relevant code), there's no need for `std::move()`, as `std::string(...)` is already an rvalue expression.

---

Other notes:

- Your local style guide may say otherwise, but we normally use `PascalCase` for names of composite types rather than for functions.  Consistency with the rest of the code base and any libraries may be a factor here, though.
- That Windows code instead of `getenv()` is horrible - I hope I never have to target Windows!  Can `_dupenv_s()` return true when it has allocated `buf`?  If so, the error path also needs to `free(buf)`.
- `buf == nullptr` can be written simply as `!buf`.
- In the Windows path, you can avoid the need for local `val` by giving `buf` to a `unique_ptr` to look after it for you (so you can simply `return buf;` or `return {};` for the success and failure cases, respectively):

  ```
    char *buf{nullptr};
    size_t sz;
    auto failed = _dupenv_s(&buf, &sz, var);
    std::unique_ptr<char,malloc_deleter> m{buf}; // ensure buf is released automatically
    return failed ? std::string{} : std::string{buf, sz};
  ```
- Actually, now I've read up on the Windows function, there seems to be no reason not to use `std::getenv()` - the only difference in behaviour seems to be if a null pointer is passed as argument, and we never do that.
- You might want to use a *raw string literal* to reduce those doubled-backslashes: `\$\{([^}]+)\}` may be slightly easier to read.
- Really, really split that single-line `while` into separate lines for the condition and statement.  It may even be worth making it a block, and giving names to the match and replacement - notably for `match[0]` which you also write as `match.begin()` in that expression.
- I'd probably write the argument to `GetEnv()` as `char const*` rather than `char const[]`, to help distinguish from actual array arguments (in templates, where the size is a template argument).
- Do you want to provide a means to escape `${` when it appears literally in the input?

---

#Reworked code

```
#include <string>
#include <regex>
#include <cstdlib>

inline std::string expand_env(std::string text)
{
    static const std::regex env_re{R"--(\$\{([^}]+)\})--"};
    std::smatch match;
    while (std::regex_search(text, match, env_re)) {
        auto const from = match[0];
        auto const var_name = match[1].str().c_str();
        text.replace(from.first, from.second, std::getenv(var_name));
    }
    return text;
}

#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << expand_env("${HOME} is where the heart is.\n");
}
```